# How can I get my GUI to display the maximum of my function?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am working on a GUI that generates a chart from the input values A and B using this equation

> f =(   1/(A*sqrt(2*pi))   )  *  exp(-0.5*((x-B)/A).^2  );

I need to find a way to display the coordinates of the graph's maximum on the GUI (both x and y). However nothing I've done has worked so far.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Have you taken the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?  For coding problems like this, we ask that you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We also ask that you demonstrate that you've made some attempt at solving the problem yourself.  That can both help us know what has been tried, and better understand what exactly your problem is.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is some more info on good questions, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
f =( 1/(A*sqrt(2*pi)) ) * exp(-0.5*((x-B)/A).^2 );
plot(f)
hold on
[a,b] = max(f);
plot(b,a ,'*r')
```

which (b,a) is the coordinates of the graph's maximum